# Can cURL send requests to sockets?

Tags: curl, sockets

I have a HTTP server running at `/var/run/my-server.sock`, and I want to test it by sending a simple request using cURL. Can this be done using cURL? Can it be done at all, or must there be a reverse proxy in place?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
curl socket:/var/run/my-server.sock:/test/path
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The feature was added in curl `7.40`.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/images/json
```

Another example:

```
curl --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket /docker.sock http:/events
```

Which specifies the `GET` explicitly (rather than assumed). And will not buffer (for `tail -f` realtime update).

(The first Ubuntu release to ship with curl 7.40 or newer was 15.10).

cURL 7.50 and up [requires a valid URL to be provided](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/936), including a hostname, so to run the above examples with cURL 7.50, a "dummy" hostname has to be added, for example:

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http://localhost/images/json
```

and

```
curl --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket /docker.sock http://localhost/events
```

Comment: And in this example I see the very socket I was going to `curl` into after all. Long live Docker!

Comment: By the way, the netcat and socat examples are no longer *above* :]

Comment: This is really useful. However, I'm trying to do this `curl --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket tcp://192.168.99.102:2376 http://events` but curl cannot connect to the server. I tried using the ruby docker library and it connects fine using this

Comment: @user1513388 I'm pretty sure you have to provide the path to a socket as the argument to `--unix-socket`, not a URI.

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04 users, there seems to be a PPA that has backports of curl 7.4x - https://launchpad.net/~mnordhoff/+archive/ubuntu/curl-backport

Comment: If the socket file is owned by `root`, these return `Couldn't connect to server` until you run `sudo curl`.

Comment: On CentOS 7 this was backported even to the 7.29 `curl` version.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure, but as per this ticket:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/feature-requests/53/

it doesn't seem to be the case.

Per this:

- https://gist.github.com/nuxlli/7553996

seems like socat or nc can do it, snip from the above snip:

```
# Socat version
echo -e "GET /images/json HTTP/1.1\r\n" | socat unix-connect:/var/run/docker.sock STDIO

# nc version (netcat-freebsd)
echo -e "GET /images/json HTTP/1.0\r\n" | nc -U /var/run/docker.sock
```

Haven't tried either myself.

Comment: it works with the exception that you can to provide `\r\n\r\n` at the end, not `\r\n`
`echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"`